# Polynomial Functions Question (Determine values of $~k~$ and $~f~$)

Tags: polynomials

The question is

> When $~2x^3 + x^2  - 2kx + f~$ is divided by $~x - 1~$, the remainder is
>   $~-4~$, and when it is divided by $~x+2~$, the remainder is $~11~$.  Determine the values of $~k~$ 
>       and $~f~$.

I know how to solve for $~k~$, you would just sub in the root for $~x~$ and set the equation equal to the remainder but because I also have to solve for $~f~$ this throws me off and I am confused as of what to do.

Comment: Sub 1 for $x$ and you'll get an equation, then sub -2 for $x$ and you'll get another equation. Can you continue from there?

Comment: @evaristegd When I plugged in 1 for $x$ I got $3-2k+f$ and when I plugged in -2 I got $-12+4k+f$. What do I do from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you replace the value of $x$ with $1$ and then with $-2$, you will get two equations. The first equation is equal to $-4$ , by Bézout's theorem. Analogously, the second equation is equal to $11$.

That's a linear system of two equations with two unknowns. 
$$-2k+f=-7 $$
$$ 4k+f=23 $$

Multiply the first equation by 2, and then add that result to the second equation. You can get the value of $f$ that way. After that, obtaining the value of $k$ should be easier.

Comment: So if you're saying the first equation will be like $2(1)^3+(1)^2-2k(1)+f = -4$ then no, I do not understand how to solve that.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $p(x)=2x^3+x^2-2kx+f$, then $p(1)=-4$ and $p(-2)=11$. So…

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to tell me. Do I have to sub in 1 and -2 for $k$ and $f$?

Comment: No. You will find $k$ and $f$ if you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}p(1)=-4\\p(-2)=11.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: @BlueElectro , no, you have to plug those numbers in for $x$. You will get two equations where the unknowns are $k$ and $f$.